# If a table has relation then load its multiple relations

Tags: mysql, laravel, lumen, eager-loading

I have a table p3. Which is the child of p2 and p2 is the child of p1.
if p3 has another child p4a then load p4a and p4b.where p4a and p4b are the child of p3.

```
->has('p1.p2.p3.p4a')->with(['p1.p2.p3.p4a','p1.p2.p3.p4b']);
also tried 
->whereHas('p1.p2.p3.p4a', function($q){
$q->with(['p1.p2.p3.p4a','p1.p2.p3.p4b']);
}

Author::->has('p1.p2.p3.p4a')->with(['p1.p2.p3.p4a','p1.p2.p3.p4b'])->where('id',1)->first();
```

Expected Result
get all records of p4a & p4b, if p4a has atleast one record.

Actual result
Get p4a & p4b even if no related records

Comment: Do you mean that if there is at least one record in ```p4a```, only then load all the "related" records from ```p4a``` and ```p4b```, and if not, no record should be fetched?

Comment: Yes @KalpashreeV.Bal

Answer (score 0):

Dilip's answer is correct also there is a way to define the number of existing to load

below example is from the documentation of laravel.
inside the function you can have all kinda conditions.would this work for you?

```
// Retrieve posts with at least ten comments containing words like foo%...
$posts = App\Post::whereHas('comments', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
}, '>=', 10)->get();
```